# How can I build Maven dependencies from Ant Java classpath?

Tags: ant, maven, dependencies, classpath, maven-ant-tasks

Using Maven Ant Tasks, I see lots of examples that build Ant classpath from Maven dependencies, but what about the other way round?

I have a carefully tuned Ant project that builds the Java task classpath from all the jars in my lib directory. How can I use Maven-Ant-tasks to use my classpath to build Maven dependencies?

I would rather not do each jar file individually (my last resort).
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

If you're working on converting from Ant to Maven, just bite the bullet and write out your `<dependencies>` section to match your ant classpath. You only have to do it once, and you'll thank yourself many times over.

Comment: I'm also upgrading packages from JDK 1.4 to JDK 6 and hoped that Maven would magically handle my version numbers.
May be that you're right, @Ryan. 
...but, wouldn't it be cool if this chore could be automated?

Comment: By "chore", do you mean generating the dependency XML from existing ant jars? It can be automated somewhat. I did it once. [Sonatype Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) has a feature that lets you search for jars by the SHA-1 checksum of the file. I happened to have set up my own Nexus server, but http://search.maven.org is one now, too. It's a relatively trivial groovy script to read in all the jars from some directory, SHA-1 them, make a request to nexus, parse out the dependency info, and stick it into XML. After that, it's just a question of excluding unneeded transitive dependencies.

Comment: Yes agreed. Using files in a lib directory means you are missing the "groupId" part of the dependency and frequently the file naming convention might be missing the "version" number.....